# VBA hacer que una misma Macro sirva para cualquier hoja

Tags: excel, vba

necesito saber si se puede hacer que una macro ejecute la orden pero que lo haga en la hoja actual y no en la que se creo. por ejemplo:

```
 Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B2:B74") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Sort
```

Selecciona las celdas de Hoja1 y las ordena por fecha. pero si quiero hacer lo mismo con Hoja2, tengo que crear otra macro para Hoja2 que haga eso mismo. ¿No hay alguna forma de utilizar una misma macro para que ejecute en la hoja en la que uno esta trabajando?, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En todos los lugares en donde tienes ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1") reemplázalo por Activesheet

Comment: Muchas gracias Abraham!! me resulto :)

Comment: DIsculpa otra consulta, si tengo esto: '''Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'02-01-2024'!R2C3:R74C4,2,0)"''' hay alguna opción para que en el BUSCARV en vez de tomar la hoja 02-01-2024, tome la hoja anterior?, por ejemplo si estoy en la hoja 04-01-2024, que me tome la de 03-01-2024, y no 02-01-2024

Comment: Para una nueva pregunta, abre un nuevo post. Saludos.